# How to Show Hide select dropdown based on select id in shopify

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-template

Hope you are doing well!!

Please let me know how to show/hide select dropdown based on select id for example:-

```
<select id="parent-{{product.id}}"><option>124</option></select>
```

For example:-

```
jquery("#parent-{{product.id}}").hide();
jquery("#parent-{{product.id}}").show();
```

Please let me know any idea. how to show and hide select dropdown using select id like in this way i write:-

```
id= parent-{{product.id}}
```

This is my real code please see

```
<div class="select">
<select id="product-select-{{ product.id }}{{ product-form }}{{ section.id }}{{ block.id }}" name="id" class="multi_select">
  {% for v in product.variants %}
      <option {% if v == variant %} selected="selected" {% endif %} data-sku="{{ v.sku }}" value="{{ v.id }}">{{ variant.title }} - {{ v.price | money_with_currency }}</option>
  {% endfor %}
</select>
</div>
```

Please let me know the valuable feedback :)

[image: Please click on this link for check my screenshot]

[image: second screenshot please check]

Comment: Have you tried using Shopify's LinkedOptionSelector code? It's a code snippet that filters options based on what the user has selected so far.  While not my favourite way to do this, it's pretty plug-n-play for many themes. https://help.shopify.com/en/themes/customization/products/variants/link-product-options-in-menus

Comment: I have tried this shopify selector code but nothing happend.